# How to set the date as NULL or INFINITY in apache tinkerpop gremlin?

Tags: date, graph, null, gremlin, tinkerpop

How to set the date as NULL or INFINITY in apache tinkerpop gremlin?

I have a field - `start_date` and `end_date`. `end_date` is optional and it's unknown. In a relational database, we can set either `NULL` or `INFINITY`.

Is there any recommended value?

Comment: Are you storing the dates using real dates or epoch integers?

Comment: If you are using integers perhaps using `-(2**63)` is as good an option as any.

Comment: Currently, storing real dates. I can change it to an integer, if that's best practice/good option

Comment: Actually with Neptune if you are comparing timestamps then using real dates is slightly more efficient. I'll compile this into an answer. Your mileage may vary with other graph databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to store INFINITY or NULL.  You have a few options.

1. If working with epoch offsets perhaps use min-int `-(2**63)` or max-int `(2**63)-1` as the definition for "no valid date set".
2. If working with ISO 8601 datetime dates then perhaps choose a date that you are confident is beyond the scope of your applications lifetime and use that. Just remember to avoid repeating the Y2K problem :-) For example `g.addV('event').property('endDate',datetime('9999-12-31'))`